# StringTokenizer и RegEx

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Делаю калькулятор. Дело дошло до разбиения на "слова".
И вот хочу применить StringTokenizer или более современный аналог для разбиения выражения на слова с учётом определённого списка разделителей.

```
String delimeters = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "==", "&&", "||", " "}; //Разделитли

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("регулярное выражение сформированное из delimeters", true);

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokens.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Как вы заметили разделитель может состоять из нескольких символов.

Пример :

```
String delimeters[] = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "&&", "||", "==", "(", ")"}    
List<String> separated = split("true||false==(false||true)", delimeters);

for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++)
    System.out.println(separated.get(i));
```

Должна напечатать :

```
true
||
false
==
(
false
||
true
)
```

Comment: Примерные строки с желаемым результатом приведёте?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

В вашем случае более правильным будет использовать простой проход по строке (ну или можно заморочиться реализацией конечного автомата)

На скорую руку

```
public class Tokenizer {
    private List<String> tokens       = new ArrayList<>();
    private String       currentToken = "";

    public List<String> tokenize() {
        String      inputString = "true||false==(false||true)";
        Set<String> delimiters  = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", " ", "(", ")", "==", "&&", "||"));

        int length = inputString.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String one = inputString.substring(i, i + 1);
            String two = i < length - 1 ? inputString.substring(i, i + 2) : "fake delimiter";
            if (delimiters.contains(one)) {
                addTokens(one);
                continue;
            }
            if (delimiters.contains(two)) {
                addTokens(two);
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            currentToken += one;
        }
        if (!currentToken.equals("")) tokens.add(currentToken);
        return tokens;
    }

    private void addTokens(String delimiter) {
        if (!currentToken.equals("")) {
            tokens.add(currentToken);
        }
        tokens.add(delimiter);
        currentToken = "";
    }
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/SdZPYg)